# Is there any way to stop Ventura from endlessly loading while typing in a directory?

Tags: finder, smb

On MacOS Ventura, when you type a path into Finder using Shift+Cmd+G, or alternately, when you type a path into a "Save As" dialog, if that path leads to an SMB share, the UI will lock up for several minutes while it "loads" something, before I even finish typing the path.

The purpose of this loading seems to be to populate a new drop down that appears while you type the path, which when typing a path that resides on the local filesystem shows the directories under the one you've typed so far. For example, if you type `/usr`, then you'll see `libexec`, `X11R6`, `lib`, and others.

But over an SMB share it just takes too long to list out all the possibilities, and Finder does it over and over. For example, if my share is mounted on `/Volumes/smb` and I want to access `/Volumes/smb/files/videos/documentaries`, Finder will list out `/Volumes`, `/Volumes/smb`, `/Volumes/smb/files`, `/Volumes/smb/files/videos`, and finally `/Volumes/smb/files/videos/documentaries`, displaying the results only momentarily before I continue typing the next directory's name.

I have resorted to saving files locally and then copying them from the command line, or going to a folder in Terminal and using the `open` command to open Finder on that directory. Both of these avoids having to list every single directory leading up to the one I'm interested in. Sometimes, when I don't feel like dealing with it, I resort to going to the other computer and working there instead of on the Mac.

The problem is worse when Finder is listing large directories with 50-300 files. Those who haven't been able to reproduce the problem on their networks probably have directories smaller than this. On my SMB server there are paths where Finder will have to list multiple directories with over 100 entries.

Is there a way to disable this new misfeature so my Mac becomes usable again?

Comment: Is this a local smb server? How's the speed outside of this function? I have shared folders, and the speed is pretty fast, so perhaps there's another issue at play. Why not use the Finder windows, rather than Go To Folder? You can select files and folders by typing their names in the standard Finder Views, and file dialogs.

Comment: So what you're telling me to do is go to /Volumes, click on `smb`, wait for that to load, then click on `files`, wait for that to load, then click on `videos`, wait for that to load.... That would take literally forever. Even worse than using the Terminal. Maybe your smb server only has a few files per directory. That would make it faster to list out the files.

Comment: What you're basically is saying is : my SMB server is really slow.

Comment: It's about as fast as a Mac, which only has wifi and not Ethernet, could possibly access it. Transfer times between my two PCs is much faster.

Comment: I installed a new router, over which my PCs with ethernet can transfer data at 1 gigabit. The Mac transfers data at 600 megabits over wifi. The problem remains. It's not the networking that's abnormally slow, it's Finder requesting unreasonable amounts of data from large directories.

Comment: @benwiggy *"What you're basically is saying is : my SMB server is really slow."* No, the problem is that macOS and iOS basically execute a `stat()`-like operation to query the extended attribute of everything in a directory before showing any files in Finder. This problematic behavior brings any HDD server to its knee regardless of how fast it normally is. Other OSes do not behave like Apple. Unfortunately, Apple doesn't have any guidance on a workaround, nor does anyone in the community it seems. Why can't Apple program Finder to do async/lazy loading instead of using a blocking operation?

Comment: It's not just Finder, but any COCOA program that will behave like this.